# Get date from a datetime in access

Tags: microsoft-access

In access query ,I only need to get the date **01/01/2012** for example from the following :

01/01/2012 9:18:35 AM

how can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

Use the DateValue() function.  So if your field name is MyDateField, your query would be like    `SELECT DateValue(MyDateField) As DateValue FROM myTableName`.